# How to get all list from a hashtable by keyset

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
@Test
public void mich() {
    Hashtable<String,List<Path>> mct = new Hashtable<String,List<Path>>();
    List<Path> mm = Arrays.asList(Paths.get("File1"), Paths.get("File2"), Paths.get("File3"));
    List<Path> bb = Arrays.asList(Paths.get("File4"), Paths.get("File5"), Paths.get("File6"));
    List<Path> dd = Arrays.asList(Paths.get("File7"), Paths.get("File8"), Paths.get("File9"));
    mct.put("A",mm);
    mct.put("B",bb);
    mct.put("C",dd);
    List<Path> result = mct.keySet().stream().filter(s -> !s.equalIgnoreCase("C")).peek(System.out::println).map(s -> mct.get(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I want my result to be

```
File1    
File2    
File3    
File4    
File5    
File6
```

How to map my Paths list?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `keySet` you have to use `entrySet` because you are using both keys and values the keys to filter and the values to get Paths, also you have to use [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) like so :

```
List<Path> result = mct.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> !"C".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getKey()))
        .flatMap(e -> e.values().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
result.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getFileName()));
```

Outputs

```
File1
File2
File3
File4
File5
File6
```

Comment: Great Job.
Thanks you